# How can I make a call from external class that extend Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

Hi guys I'm trying to make a call from a class that extends Activity but it give me a "NullPointerException" error. On the other side if I try to call the same method (that is placed in the end of MainActivity.java) from MainActivity.java it work properly. Why? How can I fix it? This is the method I call:

```
 public void prova2(){
    try{
    String url2 = "tel:33334444";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url2));
startActivity(intent);
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

and this is the call from the external class that extend application:

```
icosito.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
MainActivity prova = new MainActivity();
prova.prova2();

}
});
```

Since the method is in MainActivity.java the call from MainActivity will obviously be, prova2();

Thank you so much.

Comment: make prova2() static with a context parameter, than call MainActivity.prova2(current context);

Comment: if I make prova2(); static startActivity make this error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Activity

Comment: instead of startActivity you call context.startActivity(), what is your external class?

Comment: my external class extend activity. if I call context.startactivity(), it gives me "null pointer exception".
This is the logcat
http://pastebin.com/yNDLLbtn

Comment: What is the name of your external class?

Comment: public class Hide_Unhide extends Activity ...in this class there is the call to prova2() that is in MainActivity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63237/discussion-between-biegleux-and-jericam).